# How to prevent lagging when fetching in a large Core Data set using SwiftUI .searchable modifier?

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

Let's assume an app using Core Data with:

- A simple `Item` entity with a name (`String`) ;
- More than 20,000 items in the database.

The SwiftUI `View` below (inspired from https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10017 @ 21:00) aims to filter items by their name.

It works well in the case where there is little data. However, the interface freezes when searching in a large data set. What would be the way to prevent this?

```
struct SearchDemo: View {
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [.init(\.name)])
    var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    var query: Binding<String> {
        Binding {
            searchText
        } set: { newValue in
            searchText = newValue
            items.nsPredicate = newValue.isEmpty ? nil : .init(format: "%K CONTAINS[cd] %@", "name", newValue)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(items) { item in
                Text(item.name)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Demo")
            .searchable(text: query)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try using `NSFetchedResultsController` and using a background thread and/or concurrency. `@FetchRequest` is always on the main thread/ actor.

Comment: Your Binding property will execute a fetch request for each character typed in the search field so this solution is certainly not for large data sets. What the best solution is here depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I share this approach using `Task` I just found that works quite well!

No more UI freezing, plus a `ProgressView` while filtering items.

```
struct SearchDemo: View {
    @State private var results: [Item] = []
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var searchTask: Task<Void, Error>? = nil
    @State private var isSearching = false
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    
    static let searchTriggerDelay: Duration = .milliseconds(250)
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(results) { item in
                Text(item.name)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Demo")
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
            .onChange(of: searchText) { _ in search() }
            .overlay { if isSearching { ProgressView() } }
        }
    }
    
    private func search() {
        isSearching = true
        results = []
        searchTask?.cancel()
        searchTask = Task {
            if !searchText.isEmpty {
                try await Task.sleep(until: .now + Self.searchTriggerDelay, clock: .continuous)
            }
            try Task.checkCancellation()
            let request = Item.fetchRequest()
            request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[cd] %@", "name", searchText)
            request.sortDescriptors = [.init(SortDescriptor(\Item.name))]
            results = searchText.isEmpty
            ? []
            : try context.fetch(request)
            isSearching = false
        }
    }
}
```